# PySpark: TypeError: condition should be string or Column

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter an RDD based like below:

```py
spark_df = sc.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
spark_df.filter(lambda r: str(r['target']).startswith('good'))
spark_df.take(5)
```

But got the following errors:

```
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-86cfb363dd8b> in <module>()
      1 spark_df = sc.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
----> 2 spark_df.filter(lambda r: str(r['target']).startswith('good'))
      3 spark_df.take(5)

/usr/local/spark-latest/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in filter(self, condition)
    904             jdf = self._jdf.filter(condition._jc)
    905         else:
--> 906             raise TypeError("condition should be string or Column")
    907         return DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx)
    908 

TypeError: condition should be string or Column
```

Any idea what I missed? Thank you!

Comment: There is a perfect answer right below here ;)

Answer (score 43):

`DataFrame.filter`, which is an alias for `DataFrame.where`, expects a SQL expression expressed either as a `Column`:

```
spark_df.filter(col("target").like("good%"))
```

or equivalent SQL string:

```
spark_df.filter("target LIKE 'good%'")
```

I believe you're trying here to use `RDD.filter` which is completely different method:

```
spark_df.rdd.filter(lambda r: r['target'].startswith('good'))
```

and does not benefit from SQL optimizations.

Answer (score 5):

I have been through this and have settled to using a UDF:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType

filtered_df = spark_df.filter(udf(lambda target: target.startswith('good'), 
                                  BooleanType())(spark_df.target))
```

More readable would be to use a normal function definition instead of the lambda

Answer (score -2):

convert the dataframe into rdd.

```
spark_df = sc.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
spark_df.rdd.filter(lambda r: str(r['target']).startswith('good'))
spark_df.take(5)
```

I think it may work!

Comment: It may work, for sure. But the optimization that dataframes provide will be lost