# Create a new column with filter

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a new column that contains the count of dataframe depending on filter.

Here is an example:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|conditions                             |
+---------------------------------------+
|*                                      |
|*                                      |
|p1==1 AND p2==1                        |
```

I tried:

```py
df = df.withColumn('cardinal',df.filter(conditions).count())
```

it didn't work. The error message is:

> "filter expression 'conditions' of type string is not a boolean.;;\nFilter conditions#2043: string\n+-

Answer (score 2):

You have to use **`literal`** for your `df.filter` function.

***Try with below syntax:***

```
>>> df1 = df.withColumn('cardinal',lit(df.filter(conditions).count()))
```

Now **df1 dataframe** will have `cardinal` column added to it.

> **Update:**

i tried with simple example:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df=sc.parallelize([(1,1),(2,1),(3,2)]).toDF(["p1","p2"]) #createDataFrame
conditions=((F.col('p1')==1) & (F.col('p2')==1)) #define conditions variable
df1=df.withColumn("cardinal",F.lit(df.filter(conditions).count())) #add column
df1.show(10,False)
+---+---+--------+
|p1 |p2 |cardinal|
+---+---+--------+
|1  |1  |1       |
|2  |1  |1       |
|3  |2  |1       |
+---+---+--------+
```

(or)

Without using `conditions` variable

```
df1=df.withColumn("cardinal",F.lit(df.filter((F.col('p1')==1) & (F.col('p2')==1)).count()))
df1.show(10,False)
+---+---+--------+
|p1 |p2 |cardinal|
+---+---+--------+
|1  |1  |1       |
|2  |1  |1       |
|3  |2  |1       |
+---+---+--------+
```

(or)

using **`.where`** clause

```
df1=df.withColumn("cardinal",F.lit(df.where((F.col("p1")==1) & (F.col("p2")==1)).count()))
df1.show(10,False)
+---+---+--------+
|p1 |p2 |cardinal|
+---+---+--------+
|1  |1  |1       |
|2  |1  |1       |
|3  |2  |1       |
+---+---+--------+
```

Comment: i try it and got that message error : "filter expression 'conditions' of type string is not a boolean.;;\nFilter conditions#2043: string\n+- –

Comment: @zineb.el,in your **filter** expression make sure you have used `col`, by importing **`from pyspark.sql.fucntions import *`**, refer to this link for similar kind of issue.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880269/pyspark-typeerror-condition-should-be-string-or-column

Comment: yes i did : df1 = df.withColumn('cardinal2',F.lit(df.filter(F.col('conditions')).count()))

Comment: @zineb.el, i have updated my `answer` with simple example that i tried, If you are still facing the issue please `update your question with your code and sample data` so that we can try to **recreate** the issue on our end.